# Cannot click on SWF when small size in Mac OSX

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, macos

I have this website here http://www.innovie.com/morgan
If I use PC, I can drag and change volume on top left just fine. But if I use Mac OSX, either Safari or Firefox, I cannot drag the volume in the Flash, although I can see the mouse turn into pointer. Can someone help on why?

Where is the SWF: h**p://www.innovie.com/morgan/sound.swf

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to help -- it works for me on Safari 4, Flash version 10,0,22,87.

What happens when you try to drag? Just no effect? What browser and flash version?